# macro downloading files from IE is missing or stepping over

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code to download files from a website. Though it does not give any error but it miss some files (all files are marked downloaded).
I have criteria in excel sheet which is put into a field in the website and file is downloaded(marked downloaded in excel).

````
Dim time1, time2
Dim ie As Object

        CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
          Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
          ie.Visible = True
          ie.Navigate "websitelink"
          While ie.ReadyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
          ie.Document.getElementById("txtLogin").Value = "username"
          ie.Document.getElementById("txtPassword").Value = "password"
          ie.Document.getElementById("imgbtnLogin").Click
          While ie.ReadyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
          ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_LeftMenu1_lstLeftMenuList_ctl02_lnkItem").Click
          While ie.ReadyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
          ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_SubjectAreaMainUc1_dgSubject_ctl02_btnProcess").Click
          While ie.ReadyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
          ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_SubjectAreaDetailUc1_dgReporting_ctl04_lnkbtnReport").Click
          While ie.ReadyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

ie.Visible = True
Set objshell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
iecount = objshell.Windows.Count
NROW = 2
ROW_FLAG = Sheet1.Cells(NROW, 1).Value

Do While ROW_FLAG <> ""
        ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_SubjectAreaDetailUc1_MISEFEWiseData_txtExportNTN").Value = Sheet1.Cells(NROW, 1).Value
        ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_SubjectAreaDetailUc1_MISEFEWiseData_txtDateFrom_txtDate").innerText = Sheet1.Cells(2, 5)
        ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_SubjectAreaDetailUc1_MISEFEWiseData_txtDateTo_txtDate").innerText = Sheet1.Cells(3, 5)
        ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_SubjectAreaDetailUc1_MISEFEWiseData_btnReport").Click
        Sheet1.Cells(NROW, 3).Value = "Downloaded"
        While ie.ReadyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

'time1 = Now
'time2 = Now + TimeValue("0:01:00")
'    Do Until time1 >= time2
'        DoEvents
'        time1 = Now()
'    Loop
    NROW = NROW + 1
    ROW_FLAG = Sheet1.Cells(NROW, 1).Value
    Do While iecount <> xx
    xx = objshell.Windows.Count
    Loop
Loop

    While ie.ReadyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

      Set ie = Nothing
MsgBox Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) & Sheet1.Cells(1, 5)
End Sub```
````

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `.ReadyState` or `.Busy` properties remain unchanged when clicking button. If that's the case, you're not actually waiting to complete this action which is why it's missing some files (other than first one). Been there, done that.

You need to find a way to wait until you can download next file. I see 2 options (other than hardcoded delay):

1. if website tells you the file is downloading, loop while specific element updates, eg maybe there's a loading icon, or 'downloading' text displayed, anything? If you're not sure, get "body" innerText before and after click and compare
2. count files in your download folder before click, and wait until count is greater after click - yeah it's not ideal, but it's an option

Also, just to point out:

- I'm not sure what the `Do While iecount <> xx` does, but I would get rid of that as it might be very inaccurate
- rather than keep copying the `While ie.ReadyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend`, make it a function, it'll make your life easier and code tidier - you could add optional argument, a string that must be present in body's innerText (as mentioned above)
- you're setting IE to nothing, but browser remains open, unless it's desired you can add `IE.quit` first